# Getting type from template template method parameters

Tags: c++, templates, c++11

I'm trying to make a method that picks a random element from a container type, like `std::vector`. Before, I was using this:

```
std::string pick_random(std::vector<std::string> c) {
    int r = std::rand() % ids.size() + 1;
    auto it = c.begin();
    std::advance(it, r);
    return *it;
}
```

which, as far as I could tell, worked fine. That's not to say it *is* fine, just that it *appeared to be*.

I soon had to do the same thing for another container, so I tried using template template arguments to make the method generic:

```
template <template<typename element_t> container_t>
element_t pick_random(container_t from) { /* ... */ }
```

This, however, throws an error:

```
element_t does not name a type
```

I think my intent is clear enough, but to restate it: I'm trying to get the element type of the list. I could have a separate template parameter, but then it can't properly infer the type. I've tried various different versions, but none work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Even better would be to avoid the arbitrary restriction on class templates. After all, why not be able to pick an element from a raw array? In order to correctly name the type in C++11, we'd have to get the result of an unqualified call to `begin`, which we can get via:

```
namespace detail {
    using std::begin;

    template <typename C>
    auto adl_begin(C&& c) -> decltype(begin(std::forward<C>(c))) {
        return begin(std::forward<C>(c));
    }
}
using detail::adl_begin;
```

And then use *that* to deduce the element_type from an arbitrary container:

```
template <typename C>
auto pick_random(C& container) -> decltype(*adl_begin(container))
{ /* rest as before */ }
```

Side-note: take your container by reference, not by value.

Comment: Any chance I could get an explanation for a newb? I'm not saying that I am one, but… okay yes I am.

Comment: @QPaysTaxes What you're trying to get at is - given a container, get the value type. The value type is the result of `*begin(container)` - so this just uses that directly, rather than trying to "guess" at the value type by decomposing the container type.

Comment: I'm accepting this answer because it best generic-izes the method, even though Jarod and Sergej's answers both answer my specific question better.

Answer (score 6):

`container_t` is not a type, `container_t<T>` is.

You may use the following:

```
template <template<typename, typename...> C, typename T, typename...Ts>
T pick_random(const C<T, Ts...>& from);
```

as for `std::vector`, you have allocator: `std::vector<T, Alloc>`.

In C++14, you may simply use `auto`

```
template <typename C>
auto pick_random(const C& from) { /* ... */ }
```

Comment: Why doesn't OP's use of `element_t` get recognized as a type?

Answer (score 5):

I don't think that "template template arguments" are required here,
you could simply use the `value_type` from the container:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>
#include <vector>
#include <list>

template <typename T>
typename T::value_type pick_random(T& from) {
    int r = std::rand() % from.size();
    auto it = from.begin();
    std::advance(it, r);
    return *it;
}

int main() {
    std::srand(std::time(0));

    std::vector<std::string> words {"the", "frogurt", "is", "also", "cursed"};
    std::list<int> numbers {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};

    std::cout << "words: "   << pick_random(words)   << std::endl;
    std::cout << "numbers: " << pick_random(numbers) << std::endl;
}
```

> `value_type` - the type of the values that can be obtained by dereferencing the iterator.
>
> Source: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/iterator_traits

Answer (score 2):

If you're only using standard library containers then you can get the stored type out of them by using `container_t::value_type`.

```
template <typename container_t>
typename container_t::value_type pick_random(container_t& container)
{ ... }
```

Comment: I think you meant `container_t& container`, because `C` wasn't defined anywhere ;) Aside from that, good answer, but for whatever annoying reason the bloke who wrote this special fancy container type didn't include `::value_type`